# Files deleted from Application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a dotnet application which i have accidently deleted files from the application itself but in my sql mdf file the size of my database is still the same and also from the sql database path the size is almost 9GB. Is there a way to recover those deleted data from the application by using mdf file which is showing the data's in the tables? Please advise

I have just taken the current backup from the sql management studio just in case

Comment: Please clarify your question.  You can recover data using SSMS but you cannot recover application files like .exe, .dll, etc from the mdf.

Comment: Why not just use the code from your source control to rebuild your app? You are using source control, right?!